# Auto Arrange Rows In Tableview Based On Priority - Swift 3/4

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, swift3, rows

In my to do list app, the user can select a priority when adding a task. This priority sets the colour of an image view in each cell, as seen here:

```
cell.priorityImageView.image = UIImage(named: String(tasks[indexPath.row].priority))
```

When the priority is set, the priority(int) is either 0,1,2,3

I would like to automatically sort the rows so that all the 3s are at the top, all the 2s are under etc

Is this at all possible? and if so, how?

I have a tasks array

```
var tasks = [Task]()
```

And when a task is added, it is done through core data

```
 func AddTaskToCoreData() {
    //Access Name - Make sure to check presence
    let task = taskTextView.text!
    let taskPriority = Int16(priorityNumber)
    var date = "12:00"
    if selectedDate == true {
        let datepick = datePicker.date
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d HH:mm"
        let result = formatter.string(from: datepick)
        date = result
    } else {
        date = ""
    }

    if taskTextView.text != "" {
        let mainTask = Task(context: PersistenceService.context)
        mainTask.task = task
        mainTask.priority = taskPriority
        mainTask.notification = date
        print(selectedDate)
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        self.tasks.append(mainTask)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        taskTextView.text = ""
        refreshTaskAmount()
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Luke

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you provided more code.

If you're tableview gets its data from an array of `Task` objects, where a `Task` object has a `priority` property, you should just sort the array after a priority is updated and reload the tableview (Or you could insert in the correct place so you do not have to sort every time, but if your lists aren't massive, the time saved will be negligible):

`self.tasks = self.tasks.sorted(by: {$0.priority > $1.priority})`

This sorts tasks to have tasks with higher priority come before tasks with lower priority. Then just call `tableview.reloadData()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working but I have updated my answer with some more info :)